# Access Google Appengine datastore from Google Compute Engine via JDO/JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to access the appengine datastore via **JDO/JPA** from a java application **from within a google compute engine instance**. As far as I have seen, I can access manually as described in https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/

This works, yet this is very cumbersome - so I am looking for a simple way to use JDO/JPA/Objectivy/... to work on a higher level of abstraction. Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Remote API.

More info over here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

Comment: Is there a way to use JDO on top of the remote api? Couldn't find any, so far.